# Android button set text with html not working

Tags: android, html, button, textview

I'm trying to set button text using HTML and the button accepts the HTML ok but text shows up as white.  If I set the tag to TextView instead of Button with all else the same, the text is colored as expected.

**NOTE** It looks like an Android problem.  The same code that fails on my Android 6 device works fine on my Android 10 device.  Sigh...

Comment: Note that the `<font>` element has been [obsolete](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/obsolete.html#obsolete) for 15 years or more.

Comment: In Html that's true but this is Android-HTML. and in API34 font is still supported.  In Android HTML is more of a shortcut to spanned, right?